# Write $(z-w)$ as $a+bi$, where $z = 8 - 4i$ and $w = 8 + 4i$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

If $z = 8 - 4i$ and $w = 8 + 4i$, then write the expression $(z-w)$ in the standard form $a + bi$.

However when I do that I get $0$, because from what I assume $8-4i$ and $8+4i$ cancel each other out. Am I wrong or? It feels like it shouldn't be the answer unless I'm reading the question wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(8-4i)-(8+4i)=-8i$. The real parts cancel but the imaginary parts don't.